# how to use linux 'mail' command from a ruby file to send a mail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the below code, I have to send an e-mail on the status of the process whether it is completed, error out or timed out...

```
    def check_for_forecasts
   wait_until_time = Time.now + timeout.minutes
   loop do
       RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.info "Checking if process has finished"
     if find_token != 0
       update_completion_status
       RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.info "Process has finished"
       break
     elsif find_error != 0
       update_timed_out_field
       RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.info "Process has errored"
       break
     elsif DateTime.now > wait_until_time
       update_timed_out_field
       RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.info "Process has timed out"
       break
     else
       RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.info "Waiting for Process to finish"
       sleep(60) # if it hasn't completed then wait 1 min and try again.
     end
    end
  end
```

In general, we use linux 'mail' command only in .sh files not in the .rb files. Below is how we write the 'mail' command to send mails in .sh files.

```
 mail -s "the process has been finished" abc@xyz.com<<EOM
      The process has finished successfully.    
EOM
```

Is there any way to use the simple mail command in the .rb file? Or do I have to install any gems for the same?

Please Help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A really ugly but useful way to do the same from ruby:

```
to = "abc@xyz.com"
subject = "the process has been finished"
content = "The process has finished successfully."
`mail -s "#{subject}" #{to}<<EOM
  #{content}
EOM`
```

Comment: Hi rorra, thanks for your answer. can I put the same code in .rb file to send the mail instead of creating a function in .sh file and call it from ruby code?

Comment: yes, that's the idea, to be able to send an email from ruby by running a system command, I also wrote you how add ruby variables into the command. try to put that into a .rb file, execute it and you should get your email (just make sure to change the value of the variable **to**

Answer (score 2):

You can use backticks in Ruby to run command line instructions. So what you would want is something like:

```
`mail -s "the process has been finished" abc@xyz.com<<EOM
  The process has finished successfully.    
EOM`
```