# Send email with Ruby without SMTP server installed/running?

Tags: ruby, email, smtp, sendmail

On Mac, I can send email from command line using the command `mail`, but definitely I don't have  SMTP server installed on my MacBookPro.

So, it is possible to send email with Ruby without an SMTP server? I don't care about the speed, I just want a way to send email without additional software needed.

Comment: You haven't tried very hard to figure this out. Did you try searching Google for "ruby + smtp"?

Comment: Have you read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15807219/440967

Answer (score 5):

You could just call the `mail` command from within your Ruby code. Use `system` or  backticks or something more sophisticated like `open3` to interact with system commands... Here is a nice overview over the different methods: http://mentalized.net/journal/2010/03/08/5_ways_to_run_commands_from_ruby/

Answer (score 5):

#### About `mail` and `sendmail`

I don't know much about `mail`, but [results from a quick search](http://www.garron.me/en/mac/postfix-relay-gmail-mac-os-x-local-smtp.html) on Google seem to indicate that it uses postfix, which is the default SMTP server that is installed on Macs. In other words, you have installed and are running a SMTP server on your Macbook Pro.

#### About Ruby

> So, it is possible to send email with Ruby without an SMTP server?

Yes and No. You don't need to have a SMTP server running on the same machine as your Ruby process. In fact, you don't even need to run your own SMTP server. However, you need a SMTP server *somewhere* to send your email.

#### About SMTP

This [article on howstuffworks](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/e-mail-messaging/email3.htm) gives a good explanation of what SMTP does. Essentially, you need a SMTP server somewhere that accepts your email, talks to other SMTP servers, and passes your email on for delivery. With Ruby, you can configure [Net::SMTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/Net/SMTP.html) to connect to a SMTP server of your choice.

#### About What You Are Trying To Do

If you want to write and execute a script that will deliver a small number of email messages, create a fake email account on Gmail/Live and use their SMTP servers for sending email.

If you want to build and launch an app that will deliver emails to your users, use [Mandrill](http://mandrillapp.com), MailGun, or SendGrid. Mandrill has a free tier for you to get started.

I don't recommend running your own SMTP server for most use cases, because your emails will likely be marked as spam. (Comcast might also think that you have malware on your network.) Professional services like Mandrill will help you setup [SPF and DKIM records](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21751322-What-are-SPF-and-DKIM-and-do-I-need-to-set-them-up-) to authenticate your emails and improve sending reputation.

(If you just want to test email in dev mode, use [MailCatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/).)

#### Conclusion

Sign up for a [Mandrill](http://mandrillapp.com) account, then use [Net::SMTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/Net/SMTP.html) in Ruby to connect to their SMTP servers. No additional software is required.

Answer (score 2):

If your `mail` command is working, then you can send mail from within
ruby. And if your `mail` command is working on your mac already, then
you also already have an SMTP server working on your mac, since by
default it uses `postfix` which comes installed. The `mail` command
defaults to using `/usr/sbin/sendmail`, which is in this case an
interface to `postfix`. (Try `man sendmail` from the Terminal.)

Now, that said, you will probably experience something like this when trying to use Net::SMTP locally:

```
[3] pry(main)> smtp = Net::SMTP.start('localhost',25)
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)
```

This means that you need to do something to tell your mac that it can
accept connections on port 25. Another alternative is to use that
`sendmail` program as a transport access method, which might actually be the
better option. The port 25 access is turned off so that no one else
can use your mac as a mail relay. Having to go through the `sendmail`
command means that only programs on your mac can send mail (go
figure).

My suggestion here would be to use the `mail` gem (or `pony` if you
prefer) and configure it to use `sendmail`. From the `mail` `README`
file:

> Sending via sendmail can be done like so:
>
> ```
> mail = Mail.new do
>   from     'me@test.lindsaar.net'
>   to       'you@test.lindsaar.net'
>   subject  'Here is the image you wanted'
>   body     File.read('body.txt')
>   add_file :filename => 'somefile.png', :content => File.read('/somefile.png')
> end
>
> mail.delivery_method :sendmail
>
> mail.deliver
> ```

Likewise, if you're using `ActionMailer` you can configure it to use
`sendmail` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [Pony gem](https://github.com/benprew/pony)? It provides a really simple interface to `sendmail`, which should already be installed on your Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Is your goal to write and send email from the CLI?

There's a number of mailer gems, including [mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail). You could probably also play directly with Ruby's Net::SMTP and get something working, depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to send email without install local postfix server, just like want I can do with the mail command.

Comment: The examples on the [Net::SMTP docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/Net/SMTP.html) show how to connect to an SMTP server with or without authentication and the syntax with which to send a message.

Comment: The problem is I don't have a running SMTP server, so I don't know where to connect. I just I can use the mail command in my Mac to send email without SMTP server.

Comment: Do you have mail accounts connected to OS X that `mail` is reading?

Comment: No, actually I am finding a way in Ruby to connect to my recipient's SMTP to send the mail directly, without my own local SMTP relay.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to have an SMTP server, you just need to know where one is that you can connect to.

See [Net::SMTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/Net/SMTP.html). It's part of Ruby.

Comment: Actually I am already using Net:SMTP, but it require me to install a SMTP server in order to use. I am looking for a way to direct send email without SMTP, just like what I did in my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

If you used `mail` or `/usr/sbin/sendmail` command and your mail delivered successfully, then there was an MTA (Mail/Message transfer Agent eg. postfix, sendmail or whatever) running on your machine.

when you use your `mail` command to send a mail to `guser@gmail.com`,your `mail` command will submit the mail to local SMTP server.

(local) SMTP server will do the following tasks.

- SMTP server(MTA) will do MX lookup for gmail.com
- Connect to port 25 of MX server and hand over the mail by talking SMTP (HELO, MAIL FROM,RCPT TO,DATA commands)

Mx server will deliver the mail to the corresponding mailbox (guser).

The above answers suggest you to use Net::SMTP where you will connect to some SMTP server and hand over the mail to that SMTP server, which will again do the above tasks (of local SMTP server above) to perform the delivery.

So to send mail, u need an SMTP server. or you will have to code yourself/use some library to perform MX lookup and hand over the mail to the MX server by talking SMTP commands as per RFC 2821.